# Why does my website work in some Chrome, Opera, and Safari but not FireFox or IE?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, safari

So my website is just being started and currently it works in three of the five main browsers. It wont let me post pictures yet so I can't show anyone, but the website is [here](http://venaprisons.dx.am/)

In the ones it works in everything is exactly how I want it but in the ones it doesn't work in the background is completely white with no images or styles on anything and all the text is set to the left of the screen. If anyone could help that would be amazing! Thanks

Comment: It would make it easier for others to help you if you tried to find out what the relevant style parts are that don't work in the other browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you defined wrong type `type="tect/css"`

```
<link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="tect/css" /> /*wrong type define here*/
```

to

```
<link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: If your problem is solved, please close this question by accepting the answer.

Comment: Wow.. what a stupid error! Thank you! it works perfectly now :)

Answer (score 0):

https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/css-background-image-not-showing-in-ie.115660/ Check that post for pointers as to how to properly set backgrounds. You want to double check your css and research the most common quirks in IE. Also, your question is very unhelpful since it doesn't even mention what versions of browsers you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

the think that says Kheema Pandey is correct but there is another think that you have to consider:

there are some codes in javascript that some browsers reconize and some other they dont.

so you have to find a compatible code.

i mean in some cases it happens

Answer (score -1):

delete this line. You are basically limiting the rendering to only IE latest and chrome

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
```

Comment: ...and leave it up to IE to decide which rendering engine to use? Why would anyone choose older versions over new?

Comment: tell that to all my gov clients. In fact, I am killing myself right now trying to make it compatible in Quirks Mode when it works beautifully in all major browsers

Comment: But won't older versions simply use the latest mode they have available? Thus it is still useful.

Comment: thus my point. It is useless if you are expecting the latest version to read your site. The only time you should really use this is when you are specifying a browser to read your site in that specific version. For example, one of my client right now wants their site to be rendered in IE8 only because the rest of their applications are written for IE8. They have IE9 capability. But they want to use IE8. Without telling the browser what to use, the browser will go to 9 by default.

Comment: I don't forsee any problems right away, but if years down the road IE comes up with a IE13 Da Bomb! your site will only be rendering in Edge  because it's IE 11 and that is what you told it to do. If you were attemting a browser sniffer, this is not the way to go ;)

Comment: There is a foreseeable problem right away if you DON'T use it: IE11 decides there's something in your code which means it renders in IE8 mode and breaks everything.

Comment: I'm going to remove my downvote but I'll still do what Boilerplate recommends until a client insists otherwise.